# What is a light cone?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, metric-tensor, faster-than-light, causality

What is a [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone)? Why we can't escape the light cone? Why the speed of light being the limit for us to escape the cone the future and the past events of the light cone is that governs the future? and past?

Comment: Have you tried reading http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/spacetime/? It's always a good idea to mention your prior research; it makes it much easier for people to provide specific, helpful answers.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778). Can you edit your question to mention some things you're already familiar with or things you've found while reading about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape one's light cone requires you to exceed the speed of light. Since this is impossible, the light cone divides your future into two pieces: that part of space in which events are close enough to possibly affect you and that part of space where events are too far away to have any influence on your future.

Similarly, any event which occurred outside your past light cone could not have had any effect on your present, but may have an effect on your future.

Answer (score 0):

A light cone is the path that light travels in a spacetime diagram. Since we cannot travel faster than light (I cannot explain this, Einstein postulated this) we cannot get outside of the light cone. Also, if you flip the light cone to the past you know that within the light cone is the light that has been able to reach you, using the same reasoning as forwards in time.